# How to perform cart total for json data?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following json cart data

```
[
    {
        "product_image": "https://test.com/uploads/1601534902download (8).jpg",
        "product_name": "Anjeer",
        "price": "1200",
        "product_id": "5469",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "product_image": "https://test.com/uploads/1596541645download (12).jpg",
        "product_name": " Axe Signature Denim Cologne Talc",
        "price": "74",
        "product_id": "4090",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "product_image": "https://test.com/uploads/1596541645download (12).jpg",
        "product_name": " Axe Signature Denim Cologne Talc",
        "price": "74",
        "product_id": "4090",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

and sending it to the PHP server and there I'm retriving it as

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = json_decode($json, true);
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
    foreach ($_POST[$i] as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key : $value", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

In postman, I'm getting the response as

```
product_image : https: //test.com/uploads/1601534902download (8).jpg
product_name : Anjeer
price : 1200
product_id : 5469
quantity : 1
product_image : https: //test.com/uploads/1596541645download (12).jpg
product_name :  Axe Signature Denim Cologne Talc
price : 74
product_id : 4090
quantity : 1
product_image : https: //test.com/uploads/1596541645download (12).jpg
product_name :  Axe Signature Denim Cologne Talc
price : 74
product_id : 4090
quantity : 1
```

Now I want to calculate the cart total. So, I wrote

```
$total = $total + ($value['quantity'] * $value['price']);
        echo "'Total is'$total";
```

in foreach loop.  But I'm getting the total as

```
'Total is'0'Total is'0'Total is'1'Total is'26'Total is'26'Total is'26'Total is'26'Total is'75'Total is'91'Total is'91'Total is'91'Total is'91'Total is'140'Total is'156'Total is'156
```

How do I get the cart total properly?

Comment: Your `$value` is the value, not the array. You have to do it in the `for` loop: `$_POST[$i]['total'] = ...`

Comment: You mean 
`$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = json_decode($json, true);
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
 foreach ($_POST[$i] as $key => $value) {
  $total = $total + ($value['quantity'] * $value['price']);
        echo "'Total is'$total";
  // echo "$key : $value", PHP_EOL;
 }
}`
like this?

Comment: Why are you using `php://input` _and_ `$_POST`?  That doesn't seem to make sense. If `php://input` gives you a valid json string, then I don't see how `$_POST` can contain any data?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = json_decode($json, true);
$total = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
    foreach ($_POST[$i] as $key => $value) {
        $total = $total + ($value['quantity'] * $value['price']);
        echo "'Total is'$total"; 
    }
}
```

First thing - I wonder, why you pass the json to the `$_POST` superglobal (do you need it later on?)

But `$value` is something like `122`, `Anjeer`, `Rudolph, the Red-Nosed Reindeer`. So there is no data in `$value['quantity']`. (If you activate error reporting, you'll see a lot of messages)

So there are multiple Ways. With your loop:

```php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$total = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 
    $total = $total + $json[$i]['quantity'] * $json[$i]['price'];
}
```

If have replaced `$_POST` with `$json` and used the count of the array, as we don't know, how many results we get!

Or with a array function:

```php
$total = array_reduce($json, function ($key, $product) {
    return $product['quantity'] * $product['price'];
}, 0);
```